How to get rid of "Choose your search engine" dialog in Chrome v.127 on Selenium test run?
Since Chrome Browser updated to version 127, on Selenium tests runs I get the next dialog open:

How to get rid of it using C#?
Do I need to make some options on driver start?
I've already chosen it in my browser and it doesn't appear anymore. But for tests in happens on each run.

You can fix it with the option:
--disable-search-engine-choice-screen

See here how to set options for different programming languages: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/

I hoped that was a link documenting the option

And I hope they finally add "disable-every-annoying-thing" to the options, once and for all

Or in Python:
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")

I have these others opt and it doesn't work with version 127.0.6533.88 (arm64):
"opt.add_argument("--disable-webgl")
opt.add_argument("--incognito")
opt.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
opt.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
opt.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
opt.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
opt.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
opt.add_argument('--disable-web-security')"

Kiks73, if you still have a problem, you might need to raise a new question explaining what parameter doesn't work for you and why it's causing you a problem.

You can fix this by adding "--disable-search-engine-choice-screen" option.
Java:
if (configuration.isHeadless()) {
        return new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--headless=new"));
    } else {
        return new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen"));
    }

C#:
var options = new ChromeOptions();

        if (configuration.IsHeadless())
        {
            options.AddArgument("--headless=new");
        }
        else
        {
            options.AddArgument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen");
        }

        return new ChromeDriver(options);

List of runtime flags for Chrome to configure the environment.: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/main/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md

With Ruby on Rails / ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome do |driver_options|
    driver_options.add_argument("disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
  end
end


For C#:
public void Arguments()
        {
         ChromeOptions chromeoptions = new ChromeOptions();
         chromeoptions.AddArgument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen");
         driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }

For more reference:
You can visite the seleniumhq.github.io
